# How can I access QAbstractTableModel Data from QML Repeater

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've been struggling for a few days trying to figure out how to display some pretty simple data in a QML window.  I realize there are many ways to accomplish this task, and in this case, I'd prefer to find out how to use QAbstractTableModel.

I have a row of data, each row containing two items, a name and a value (name/value or key/value pair).  I've subclassed the QAbstractTableModel to pass this data to the QML.  Here is the code I have so far; it is mostly based on the tutorial that can be found here (which is also very old): https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-addressbook.html.

## databridge.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QPair>

class DataBridge : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataBridge();
    explicit DataBridge(QList<QPair<QString, QString>> listOfPairs);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role);
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent);
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QList<QPair<QString, QString>> getList();

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QList<QPair<QString, QString>> m_listOfPairs;

};

#endif // DATABRIDGE_H
```

## databridge.cpp

```
#include "databridge.h"

DataBridge::DataBridge()
{}
DataBridge::DataBridge(QList<QPair<QString, QString> > listOfPairs)
{  m_listOfPairs = listOfPairs; }

int DataBridge::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_listOfPairs.size();
}

int DataBridge::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    //Number of columns is always 2 in this kata
    return 2;
}

QVariant DataBridge::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(index.row() >= m_listOfPairs.size() || index.row() < 0)
        return QVariant();
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        QPair<QString, QString> pair = m_listOfPairs.at(index.row());
        if(index.column() == 0)
            return pair.first;
        else
            return pair.second;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool DataBridge::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    //TODO
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant DataBridge::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    //TODO
    return QVariant();
}

bool DataBridge::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    //TODO
    return true;
}

bool DataBridge::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    //TODO
    return true;
}

Qt::ItemFlags DataBridge::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

    return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QList<QPair<QString, QString> > DataBridge::getList()
{
    return m_listOfPairs;
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QPair>
#include "databridge.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QList<QPair<QString, QString>> inserter;
    inserter.append(QPair<QString, QString>("0", "zero"));
    inserter.append(QPair<QString, QString>("1", "one"));
    inserter.append(QPair<QString, QString>("2", "two"));
    inserter.append(QPair<QString, QString>("3", "three"));
    inserter.append(QPair<QString, QString>("4", "four"));

    DataBridge * bridge = new DataBridge(inserter);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("bridge", bridge);

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component{
        id: myComponent
        Row{
            id: thisRow
            Text{
                text: bridge.data(index, 0)
            }
            Text{
                text: "\t.\t.\t.\t"
            }
            Text{
                text: bridge.data(index, 0)
            }
        }
    }

    Column{
        id: thisColumn
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        Repeater{
            id: myRepeater
            delegate: myComponent
            model: bridge
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("DEBUG main.qml");
    }
}
```

Please ignore the functions with TODO in them in the databridge.cpp.  I didn't include the bodies for the sake of brevity.

The first problem I'm facing is that when my repeater in the main.qml calls bridge.data(index, 0), the index is determined to be invalid in the first if statement of the data function (if(!index.isValid()).  I'm not sure why this is happening.  The second issue I can see, though I haven't gotten that far yet, is how can I tell the data function if I'm calling column 0 or column 1?  It checks for this later in the function, and returns the pair relevant to the column requested.  I'm guessing that in myComponent, I need something more specific to request the data from whichever column, but I'm not sure what that would be?

Any help with this would be immensely appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

[QModelIndex Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html)

[Another link to the example referenced at the top](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-addressbook.html)

[QAbstractTableModel Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html)

[Qt Role Enum Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution, but I'm not sure if it's the correct one.  I've added a function to the databridge class that takes integer input from the QML, finds a corresponding QModelIndex, and pulls the data from the model that way.  This is what the code looks like:

## From databridge.cpp

```
QString DataBridge::getThisItem(int index, int column)
{
    QModelIndex currentIndex = QAbstractTableModel::index(index, column);
    QString retVal = data(currentIndex, 0).toString();
    return retVal;
}
```

## Corresponding QML Repeater Change

```
Component{
    id: myComponent
    Row{
        id: thisRow
        Text{
            text: bridge.getThisItem(index, 0)
        }
        Text{
            text: "\t.\t.\t.\t"
        }
        Text{
            text: bridge.getThisItem(index, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the desired output, that being:[image: Output of program]

I am interested to know if this is a good implementation, or if there is a better way to do this.  Thanks again!